# Add search-exempt "do-my-work-for-me" tag with immediate bounty

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

It's very simple. Sometimes as developers we want to get some trivial task done, but it requires learning a bunch of stuff to accomplish the task someone else could probably do in about 10 seconds. If you ask it on Stack Overflow it is flagged and closed because you aren't showing what you have tried, etc... **and for good reason.**

But sometimes I want to do something really simple with CSS, and I literally want someone to do it for me and give them a bounty immediately. I know this creates more white noise so to combat this simply exempt this from the search results and stuff and give people a way to just do trivial tasks for free reputation points. I would gladly give away my reputation points for these tasks and instead spend the time helping others on here.

Add a specific tag to cover this that helps to filter it out. Make bounties immediately available to offer on this tag only.

Comment: SO is not a place to hire developers, even if you are "paying" them in reputation instead of real money.  Besides, this proposal defeats the purpose of the reputation system.  People could acquire huge scores answering questions that are worthless to the community as a whole.

Comment: Makes more sense than offering a bounty then answering it yourself

Comment: My Friend, as Emily Dickinson said in an old poem  - "Tell all the truth but tell it slant"  ... *shsshhhhhh* - this is what StackOverflow is for me, but I just  embellish it with code and efforts .  Not sure what the point of this tag would be, other than to turn off people. You already can use bounties to lure more help. Above all... Nobody wants to feel *used*...

Comment: Have you heard of Amazon MechanicalTurk by the way? If you need a bot-net of digital labor...

Comment: @alib_15 - puzzled me there

Comment: I do see some potential in the idea of having more flexibility with bounties, in generall.... just not sure how.  And not without a buffer time-period like the current system of 2-days

Answer (score 21):

Stack Overflow reputation isn't a currency to trade to get your work done without learning. If you want to do that, you should hire a developer and pay them real money.

We do have the bounty system in place that allows you to spend a little bit of reputation to get an answer, but that's only for questions and answers that would benefit the site and the entire community. That's why there's a two-day wait time before you can post a bounty, to give you a chance to get an answer for free by posting a high-quality question, and to give the community a chance to close down do-my-work-for-me questions.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the 2-day wait for bounties... it had eluded me before(i.e. why can't I ask a bounty immediately )

Comment: "You should hire a developer and pay them real money" - I wonder if you read my question, it is around trivial tasks such as applying some CSS animation to your HTML snippet on a side project.  Who would hire someone else for such a trivial task?

Comment: @PWKad Your question doesn't contain the words "side project." Did you read it yourself?

Comment: How true, it sure doesn't contain that exact phrase but it does contain the words 'Sometimes as developers we want to get some trivial task done' so I was hoping you could infer that A: I am a developer and B: A trivial task is not 'Build my site for me' or 'Design my site'.  Thanks for the snarky comments though, glad I could come here to meta and make a suggestion and feel so welcome.  Always remember after doing so why it's the cool kids club.

Comment: @PWKad There's nothing snarky in my answer. Furthermore, I don't see how it matters that you're a developer, or if you think some tasks are trivial. I pay other people to do trivial tasks for me all the time. Mow the lawn, rake the leaves, make me a sandwich. There's nothing wrong with paying people to do tasks you just don't feel like doing yourself.

Comment: Always gotta have the last comment huh?  I said your comment was snarky not your answer.

Comment: @PWKad And yours wasn't?

Comment: Ah ,   in other news, it's hump-day ya'll  let's cheer up

Comment: @PWKad There's really no need to hire anyone, there's plenty of freelancers around who'll be happy to charge by the hour to do whatever it is that needs done, and after the fact you simply pay them and part ways.